# De un string buscar la palabra y agregar a un array

Tags: javascript, array, string, find

Necesito obtener mi cadena, que devuelve todo en una fila y lo separa por patrones.

Por ejemplo, como se ve en el texto a continuación, necesito que si encuentra la palabra detente, corte la cadena y me la devuelva en una matriz, luego, la próxima vez que encuentre la palabra, la cortará y así sucesivamente con la tercera. cual seria andres.

Debido a que necesito separarlo en 3 arreglos, estaba tratando de hacerlo con división, pero no obtengo el resultado que necesito. Soy nuevo en javascript y tal vez haya una manera más fácil de hacerlo de lo que imagino. muchas gracias espero me puedan ayudar.

```
var texto = "Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking 
at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed 
by 
and made him stop. stop soldier, I want to ask you a question 
Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't 
seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is My husband is 
tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat 
it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written 
San Andres"


//Necesito que me devuelva asi: 
//Ejemplo: 
let primerSeccion = ["Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed by and made him stop"]
let segundaSeccion = ["I want to ask you a question Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is"]
let terceraSeccion = ["My husband is tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written San Andres"]

//Lo que intente fue lo siguiente.. 
//Si texto incluye la palabra stop. Deberia cortar la ejecucion y hasta donde llego deberia guardar en un arreglo. 
let primerSeccion = [];
let segundaSeccion = [];
let terceraSeccion = [];
//Intente varias formas que fui encontrando.. Pero ninguna se acerca un poco a lo que necesito.
console.log(texto[0,6] === "Catherine")
console.log(texto.includes('stop'))
var ahora = texto.find(elemento => elemento === 'stop')
console.log(ahora);
for (let index = 0; index < texto.length; index++) {
  return texto.includes("stop")
  
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo no entiendo muy bien, quieres que el primer string se parta cuando encuentre la palabra "stop"? es que en tu descripcion no me cuadra el resultado que esperas. Puedes aclarar mejor? Por ejemplo, después de la primera palabra stop que se encuentra sigue "him stop. stop soldier, I want to ask..." el "stop soldier" no veo que aparezca en ninguno de los resultados que esperas, también en tu variable "segundaSeccion" hay texto que no está en el ejemplo. Puedes revisar y aclarar si el ejemplo que tienes y lo que esperas es correcto?

Comment: ahi edite mi pregunta y subi una imagen para que veas que es lo que espero. Parece que no se veía completa la pregunta..

Comment: Lo que pides no parece concordar con la imagen. Veamos, quieres conseguir tres partes del texto. Eso se entiende. Pero lo que no está claro es en que te basas par cortarla. La primera parece ir desde el inicio hasta stop, pero la seguna va desde ¿Stop hasta?. No veo como sabes donde cortar, no encuentro un patrón claro.

Comment: La segunda deberia cortar en "seen my husband who went to war one day?" con el parentesis.. Y después toda la demas

Answer (score 1):

Dado que la pregunta es al parecer demasiado explicita y necesitas cortar las palabras de una manera especial.

Aqui te dejo una solucion, la primera frase se corta cuando encuentra "stop." (basado en la respuesta que esperas) y la segunda frase se corta en el "he is" (basado de nuevo en la respuesta que esperas)

```js
var texto = "Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed by and made him stop. stop soldier, I want to ask you a question Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is My husband is tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written San Andres";

let [seccion1, rest] = texto.split("stop.", 2); //Partimos la palabra por stop. (ese texto se quita)
seccion1+="stop."; //Le añadimos esa misma palabra a la seccion 1

let [seccion2, seccion3] = rest.split("(how) he is",2); //hacemos lo mismo con la seccion restante
seccion2+="(how) he is"; //Le agregamos el final que le quitamos

console.log(seccion1)
console.log(seccion2)
console.log(seccion3); //La seccion 3 no se modifica
```

No entiendo porque necesitas que las secciones sean un array, pero si así las necesitas, sencillamente metes el valor en un array: `[seccion1]`

Comment: Muchas gracias.